# How can I match two lines with the same regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, regular-language

I need to match these two texts:

```
Last dying gasp time : -

Last dying gasp time : 2021-08-13 18:27:44
```

What I tried is

- `Last dying gasp time\s+:\s+[\d-]+\s+[\d:]+`
- `Last dying gasp time\s+:\s+[\d-]`
- `Last dying gasp time\s+:\s+[\d-]+(\s+[\d:]+)?`

But it only matches one or the other. How can I achieve this?

Comment: ...or just `Last dying gasp time\s*:.*` if you are not particular about what follows the colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
^Last dying gasp time\h*:\h*(?:-|\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2}\h+\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2})$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cxXcTH/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `Last dying gasp time`: Match text `Last dying gasp time`
- `\h*:\h*`: Match `:` surrounded with 0 or more spaces on both sides
- `(?:-|\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2}\h+\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2})`: Match a `-` or a date-time string
- `$`: End

Answer (score 0):

You can use a group reference `\<n>` where `<n>` is a digit, to indicate a match of the preceding group number (the group mus have been matched, so you cannot make it match in advance)

```
/(Last dying gasp time :).*\n\1.*/
```

you first surround the regular expression into a group... you then match the rest of the line (this is what `.*` is for), then you match the `\n`, and then you make reference to what was matched in that first group, `\1`, followed by the rest of the line (`.*`).  The good thing is that you are not forced to use a fixed string, so you could get all the lines with the same first part(And demonstrated on this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JEFpYh/1)):

```
(^[^:\n]+:).*(\n\1.*)*
```

this is, a group formed of anything from the beginning of a line, except a colon or a new line, followed by a colon, followed (the group) by anything upto any number of sequences of a new line, followed by the last group matched string of characters, followed by anything upto a new line, any number of times.  If you are interested only in groups of at least two repeated headers, just change the last asterisk by a plus sign.

```
(^[^:\n]+:).*(\n\1.*)+
```